# Javascript arrays merge

Tags: javascript

`

I have two arrays

```
a = [a0,a1,a2,..]
b = [b0,b1,b2,..]
```

How to obtain the below array

```
c=[[a0,b0],[a1,b1],[a2.b2],[.,.]...]
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is to help you with your problems not to get code for free. Please share if you have tried anything. If not, try and add it in question

Comment: This is what I tried (https://jsfiddle.net/erwdg94s/) but didn't got the answer what i expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array#map` method, and use the index parameter to get the relevant element from the second array.`map` method return a new array

```js
var a = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2']
var b = ['b0', 'b1', 'b2']

var c = a.map(function(item, index) {
  return [a[index], b[index]]
})
console.log(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help .. That worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
function merge(a, b) {
    var c = [];
  a.forEach((item, index) => {
    c[index] = [item];
  })
  b.forEach((item, index) => {
    c[index].push(item);
  })
  return c;
}
```

Comment: I am unable to understand it , i tried here https://jsfiddle.net/x1pb76ug/ , please help me